# File path autocomplete in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Has VS Code an autocomplete function for file paths? 
For e.g. if I want to write the full path to js: `"assets/libs/jquery.min.js"`
Editors like Brackets.ie does this by default.

Comment: I'm hoping they add this, it doesn't come up with suggestions as I type and it's not super necessary, but would be cool. The main reason for using VS code over something like Sublime Text is that a lot of stuff is setup by default and appears to have good debugging built in for Node.JS apps. I may end up switching back to sublime though and just configuring it

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Visual code by itself has no Path intellisense, but you can use this plugin.

press f1 and copy this in it:  **ext install path-intellisense**

Its a plug-in made by Christian Kohler, all props to him.

Plus, as Searene mentions in the comments, you may also want to set `"path-intellisense.absolutePathToWorkspace": false` in User Settings to make the auto-completion of absolute paths work.

Comment: it doesn't recognize tilde (~) as root directory

Comment: You may also want to set `"path-intellisense.absolutePathToWorkspace": false` in `User Settings` to make the auto-completion of absolute paths work.

Comment: I think @Searene's comment should be added to the answer.

Comment: I do think this functionality has been integrated into VS Code. This works for me, with `~`, out of the box.

Answer (score 12):

[Path Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense&ssr=false#overview) does not work for me, but [Path Autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete&ssr=false#overview) works for me.

**Installation**:

Launch VS Code Quick Open (Ctrl+P), paste the following command, and press enter.

```
ext install ionutvmi.path-autocomplete
```

You can also install it in the extensions tab(Ctrl+Shift+X).

Comment: same with me. Path intellisense always show paths from root workspace when I press "../". Path autocomplete works very well.

Comment: you may need to add `"typescript.suggest.paths": false` and `"javascript.suggest.paths": false` in vscode settings. did and works perfectly fine!