# Only image added not the extension

Tags: image

I recently re-installed VSC and I'm having a strange issue in my HTML files.
I remember I was used to using the autocomplete function to get an instant list of the images I wanted to insert, then I was choosing one and then VSC would add it to my code in the form of filename.jpg
This time, when I try to do the same thing, I only get the filename and then I have to type the extension manually.
What am I missing?

Comment: It's going to be impossible to help you with the problem without seeing your code. Please share your HTML and other related code

Comment: This is an example of what I mean.
Autocomplete with the image:
https://s17.postimg.org/ltvrckd7z/Clipboard01.jpg

After I picked the image from the list:
https://s17.postimg.org/c9c4pq5wf/Clipboard02.jpg

The result is without the file extension.
I'm sure Visual Studio Code can add the extension as well, but for some reason, I only get the filename.

Comment: Perhaps you can try the extension as explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658717/file-path-autocomplete-in-vs-code , not sure if it will work

Comment: Just a heads up, your question might be flagged as off-topic because you are asking help with a setting in a tool and might not be seen as a programming related question

Comment: Thank you, not sure how to edit my question in order to avoid the OT at this point.
I actually have the intellisense installed already, it seems there's an issue with the period in Windows.

Comment: Is your file extensions showing in file explorer on Windows or is it hidden?